# Creating MultiDiGraph using networkx with .dat file give

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

Hi I wonder how to create a MultiDigraph using networkx when I have graph representation given in .dat file? Exemplary data in that file looks like this:

```
1 2 0.5
2 3 0.4
2 3 0.3
1 3 1.0
```

Is there any built in function to do so? Or where should I search for any useful information about it?

Comment: Generally the library documentation will provide all relevant information about supported input formats.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm aware of but in fact I couldn't find it :/

Answer (score 1):

You could use [read_edgelist](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.readwrite.edgelist.read_edgelist.html):

```
import networkx as nx

graph = nx.MultiGraph()
nx.read_edgelist('edges.dat', create_using=graph, nodetype=int, data=(('weight', float),))

for u, v, _ in graph.edges:
    print(u, v, graph.get_edge_data(u, v))
```

**Output**

```
1 2 {0: {'weight': 0.5}}
1 3 {0: {'weight': 1.0}}
2 3 {0: {'weight': 0.4}, 1: {'weight': 0.3}}
2 3 {0: {'weight': 0.4}, 1: {'weight': 0.3}}
```

Note that this reads the graph from a file named `'edges.dat'` with the specified format:

```
1 2 0.5
2 3 0.4
2 3 0.3
1 3 1.0
```

The function creates the graph and for each puts the `weight` as an attribute in a dictionary of dictionaries.

Comment: Thanks for that complex answer :D Greetings